# How to use Bouncy Castle to get the certification path between a root CA and an end entity when I dont have the Intermediate certs?

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, java-security

I have an end entity and a Root CA. Using this, I have to build a certificate path. Can I do this using Bouncy Castle provider. I tried the CertPathBuilder but get the error : "No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found." This is because the issuer of my EE is not in the cert list input to the builder. Is there a way to make the provider download it using AIA information, I know this is possible in SUN provider.

Comment: Do you have actual working code proving it's possible with SUN provider?

Comment: Yes. Followed the code as given - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#BuildingClasses